# IE8 problem with Jquery positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I am trying to position a loading graphic in the middle of the view window using jquery. The solution I came up with works in all browsers except IE8 or older:

JS

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery("#loading_spinner").css("left", window.innerWidth/2);
        jQuery("#loading_spinner").css("top", window.innerHeight/2);
      });
    </script>
```

HTML

```
       <div id='GB_overlay' style="display:none;">
        <div id="loading_spinner" style="position:absolute;">
          <img src="/img/transparent_loader.gif" alt="#"/>
        </div>
```

For some reason, in IE8 or lower, the spinner gets positioned in the top left corner of the screen not the center. Is this an IE bug? How can I fix this?

Comment: What doctype is the page using? It's possible that IE is rendering the page in quirks mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight which do not work on IE.

It's safest to use jQuery to work this out, use one of the following as required,

```
$(window).height();   // returns height of browser viewport
$(document).height(); // returns height of HTML document
```

Answer (score 3):

Innerwidth and innerheight are not supported in IE.(except IE9)

See [**quirksmode**](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html)

You can use

`$(window).height()` and `$(window).width()`

Answer (score 0):

Try using

http://api.jquery.com/height/